# "Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03)" isn't being detected as wireless card

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

My computer is an ASUS ROG G750 and the wireless does not work. I've looked on the Kali forums but and I noticed that this seems to be a frequent issue but could not find anything useful. When I run an `lspci` I get:

```
Network contoller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03)
```

Which is my internal wireless card that came with my computer. When I type `iwconfig` all Ii get is:

```
eth0 no wireless extensions
lo no wireless extensions
```

No `wlan0` or anything at all. I did download a Linux driver for the wireless card but noticed that it supports:

```
4329
432a
432b
432c
433d
4365
```

And so on but it does not mention mine. I saw on one forum that somebody recommended some program that utilizes Windows XP drivers but I did not find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this site worked for me
http://www.kalilinux.net/community/threads/how-to-make-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-card-work-in-kali.814/

Comment: Please post the most important or helpful parts of a link inline (it helps avoid link-rot).

Comment: too late, it's a broken link, now.